# Latexit not showing the right boundary when using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, latexit

Trying trying to use [LatexIt](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) to make some standalone figures. The issue is that the right-most boundary does not show up:

[image]

The preamble that I'm using is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
```

and here's the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
\draw (-5,-5)-- (5,-5)--(5,5)--(-5,5)--(-5,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have run the same code on Overleaf and TeXShop and it returned a full square, so I am guessing that the issue is on LatexIt's end. I have checked the margin (in the preferences) and they were all 0.00pt.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be **a problem related to various display algorithms involved**, e.g. Latex, Latex-editor, operating system. I use MikTex on Windows, BTW.

First, I wonder why a severe error isn't flagged: you dropped \begin{document} and \end{document}.

When I disable the first 4 packages, as they aren't needed here, I obtain with this code what you were missing:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
%\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
%\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %useful to type directly diacritic characters
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document} % <<< DON'T MISS IT
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
   \draw (-5,-5)-- (5,-5)--(5,5)--(-5,5)--(-5,-5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} % <<< DON'T MISS IT
```

[image: Result with standalone]

(It might change on your computer, when you resize or zoom the window, but that's not guaranteed.)

If I use article as documentclass, it's clearly visible:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % <<<

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
   \draw (-5,-5)-- (5,-5)--(5,5)--(-5,5)--(-5,-5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result with article]

**P.S.:** I add some remarks regarding your comment [Latexit not showing the right boundary when using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640575/latexit-not-showing-the-right-boundary-when-using-tikz/640580?noredirect=1#comment1596529_640580) .

1. Though Latexit doesn't require the \begin-\end environment for documents you'll get a constant complaint whenever you post its code here. Simply because we can't copy&compile right away. This community is willing to help, for free, so ...
2. From your and my post it's clear, we deal with a display problem, where Latexit plays its part. To further track it down I suggest doing more variations in Latexit, which do or could impact rendering, compile and analyse the outcomes.

Such variations include amongst others:

- changing the document class
- changing line thickness
- adding or shifting points, e.g. a 5th inside, or a corner at (-4,4)
- changing scales and boundaries
- etc.

3. From your link I see indication that Latexit can be a trouble maker:

> Should LaTeXiT be categorized, it would be an equation editor. This is
> not the plain truth, since LaTeXiT is "simply" a graphical interface
> above a LaTeX engine.

Which we could read as "well, it can render Latex, but may be not all of it".

4. If you have a look here some questions may point into the direction I just lined out. See e.g.:

- from tag-search: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latexit
- from the Related column to your post: [LaTeXiT not rendering tikz code properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603873/latexit-not-rendering-tikz-code-properly)
- from entering Latexit into the seach field on top: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=LatexIt

5. My guess from this survey is that Latexit will probably leave you disappointed in the sense that it can handle a lot of Latex code, but might fail in certain situations (on top of a frequent effect that sometimes Latex packages don't cooperate well anyway).
6. If everything else fails you still can, and perhaps should, report back to the developer(s) of Latexit.

Comment: Thanks but my question is specifically about the software LatexIt. In LatexIt, you do not need \begin{document}. As I mentioned at the end of my post, everything works fine when using other software.

Comment: Kindly check further information after "P.S."